# Update 2 mysql rows using CASE WHEN THEN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, case

I found this syntax for updating 2 mysql rows with one query. It looks like great logic, however I can't get it to work the way I want.

If someone could tell me if this syntax is wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.
Am I understanding this correctly?

```
$id_active = 1;
$id_swap = 2;

UPDATE article_test
// the column to update is 'sort_id' and since it is also the column I need to test,  then I use the same value for CASE right?
SET sort_id = CASE sort_id
WHEN $id_active THEN $id_swap  // sort_id 1 to become sort_id 2
WHEN $id_swap THEN $id_active // sort_id 2 to become sort_id 1
WHERE sort_id IN ($id_swap,$id_active) // test only rows with sort_id 1 & sort_id 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE article_test
SET sort_id =
  CASE 
    WHEN sort_id = $id_active THEN $id_swap  
    WHEN sort_id = $id_swap THEN $id_active 
    ELSE sort_id
  END
WHERE sort_id IN ($id_swap, $id_active)
```

**Note That:**

- You have to specify the `END` clause.
- If you didn't specify a `ELSE` clause then the default is `NULL`.

**Update2:** To clarify this, `CASE` has two syntaxs. The first one is the simplified like so:

```
CASE sort_id
  WHEN $id_active THEN $id_swap  
  WHEN $id_swap   THEN $id_active 
  ELSE sort_id
END
```

You see, the `sort_id` is specified only once after the `CASE` keyword. But what if you want to add a condition like `sort_id IN (1, 2, 3)` or `otherfield LIKE ''`. You can't add these conditions in this simplified syntax. You have to write it the other way without the `sort_id` listed after the `CASE` keyword like so:

```
CASE 
  WHEN sort_id = $id_active THEN $id_swap  
  WHEN sort_id = $id_swap   THEN $id_active 
  WHEN sort_id LIKE '' THEN blah
  ELSE sort_id
END
```

When use the `CASE` expression, with any of the these  the two syntaxs, with the `UPDATE`statement you have to write the `WHERE` clause after the end of the `CASE` expression. You can't mix it inside the `CASE` expression write it in the end of the `UPDATE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't understand this line though..
WHERE sort_id IN ($id_swap, $id_active)  THEN 'something else'

What would be the 'something else'?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my original post. I hit the return button thinking it would give a line-break, but it just posted my first sentence :P

WHERE sort_id IN ($id_swap, $id_active) THEN 'something else' What would be the 'something else'?

Comment: @Buddy -  Sorry I just noticed it is `WHERE`, I thought it is `WHEN`. In this case you have to move it to the end of the update clause see my edit. Sorry for  that.

Comment: Ah so I can put the WHEN + THEN after CASE if I am not testing another column in WHERE.
Thank you so much for this, something new I have learned! :-)

Answer (score 1):

you need to end your case statement with an `ELSE...END` like this:

```
UPDATE article_test
SET sort_id = CASE sort_id
WHEN $id_active THEN $id_swap  
WHEN $id_swap THEN $id_active 
else sort_id end
....
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about end. :)